# Graphics invert colors on HDMI monitor after waking from suspend

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, graphics, hdmi

I have two monitors on my computer, both of which work well in general. When I wake it up from suspend, the colors on many system-specific windows (eg. file browser) are inverted.

[image: Colors inverted on right monitor]

The colors are inverted on the right monitor, but work fine on the left monitor. This is repeatable, and only happens when waking from suspend. If I do a screen capture, then the colors are correct.

Any ideas about how to fix this? Here are some computer specifics:

[Monitor Model: Asus VE228H](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824236100)

[Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-Z77X-D3H](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128546)

[Graphics Card: XFX Radeon HD 6870](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814150561)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 and installing the most recent updates seems to have fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
Option         "ColorSpace" "RGB"
```

in the Section "Screen" from the file etc/X11/xorg.conf

Disable DPMS if this occur after suspend.

```
xset -dpms  <----- only disble it !
```

If the file xorg.conf does not exist:

```
sudo gedit  /etc/modprobe.d/radeon.conf
Option "ColorSpace" "RGB"
```

Comment: I tried this but couldn't get the commands to work. I don't have the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and running the commands that you suggested gave errors. I ran them without the last option (`xset -dpms` and `xset +dpms`) but that didn't seem to have an effect. Any other suggestions?